# Rust empty explicit generic argument for Option<impl Fn(i64)>

Tags: generics, rust, closures

I have `Option<impl Fn(i64) -> i64>` as an argument to a function `apply()` and I want to pass `None` value. `apply(None)`. How do I write the `apply(None)` function call correctly so it compiles?

```
fn main(){
    let a = apply(Some(|i| i + 1));
    
    let b = apply(None);
    let b2 = apply(None::<dyn Fn(i64) -> i64>);
    
    println!("a: {0}; b: {1}", a, b)
}

fn apply(f: Option<impl Fn(i64) -> i64>) -> i64 {
    let i = 0_i64;
    match f {
        Some(f) => f(i),
        None => i,
    }
}
```

compile error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |     let b = apply(None);
  |                   ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Option`
  |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
  |
4 |     let b = apply(None::<T>);
  |                       +++++

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:4:16
   |
4  |     let b = apply(None);
   |             ----- ^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Option`
   |             |
   |             required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `_: Fn<(i64,)>` found in the following crates: `alloc`, `core`:
           - impl<A, F> Fn<A> for &F
             where A: Tuple, F: Fn<A>, F: ?Sized;
           - impl<Args, F, A> Fn<Args> for Box<F, A>
             where Args: Tuple, F: Fn<Args>, A: Allocator, F: ?Sized;
note: required by a bound in `apply`
  --> src/main.rs:10:25
   |
10 | fn apply(f: Option<impl Fn(i64) -> i64>) -> i64 {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `apply`
help: consider specifying the generic argument
   |
4  |     let b = apply(None::<T>);
   |                       +++++

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0282, E0283.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
```

I tried `let b2 = apply(None::<dyn Fn(i64) -> i64>);` but it still doesn't compile the errors are

```
 Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Fn(i64) -> i64` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
5 |     let b2 = apply(None::<dyn Fn(i64) -> i64>);
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Fn(i64) -> i64`
note: required by a bound in `None`
 --> /rustc/eb26296b556cef10fb713a38f3d16b9886080f26/library/core/src/option.rs:567:5

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

Comment: It's not possible to use a trait object in an enum:
https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-doesnt-option-support-dyn-trait/45353/2

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question correctly, but since `apply` only needs *any* type which is a callable of a given signature, a `&dyn Fn(i64) -> i64` will suffice. So the syntax is `apply(None::<&dyn Fn(i64) -> i64>)` (notice the `&`). That is, the `None`-Value of an `Option` that is a (sized) reference to a dynamic type that is a callable of the given signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `dyn Fn(i64) -> i64` is unsized, meaning you can't store it in an enum like `Option`.

But a trait object reference is sized, so you can use `&dyn` instead:

```rust
apply(None::<&dyn Fn(i64) -> i64>);
```

However, it's probably better to use a function pointer type instead:

```rust
apply(None::<fn(i64) -> i64>);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec1054c05d405ea2d69e5fe2af65dd05)

Comment: I didn't know about function pointers at all, so far I have seen only the three traits `Fn`, ... . Thanks . I suppose the difference is that function pointer is simple single pointer whereas the dyn Fn is a fat double pointer is that correct?

Comment: Yep, you got it.